# Matrices with unknown values questions and solutions please

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, online-resources

I am not sure if this question should be posted don this site but it is to do with understanding math so...

I have a exam coming up and with Covid-19 the matrices part of the exam has been changed to have unknown values int the augmented matrix.

I have no question to practice with and can only find a few online.

If their are any good links for this or past exams it would be a great help.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understand what kind of question you're asking about. Could you give us an example of a problem involving "unknown values in the augmented matrix"? Perhaps you could give us a link.

Comment: You might find the problems [here](https://www.lem.ma/books/AIApowDnjlDDQrp-uOZVow/problems) to be useful

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Here is a link to one of the videos I have found https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_fOZRD2i2Jc

Comment: Perfect, thanks

Comment: Actually, [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&sxsrf=ALeKk02vniuoc6MY5dFCsDb5RoXSEMn4Fw%3A1588949633119&ei=gXK1XuzxBo25ggfJqIm4BA&q=find+the+values+of+k+infinitely+many+solutions&oq=find+the+values+of+k+infinite&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgAMggIIRAWEB0QHjIICCEQFhAdEB46BAgAEEc6AggAOgYIABAKEEM6BAgAEAo6BggAEBYQHlDFMVi2OGD_P2gAcAF4AIABqgGIAZcIkgEDMi43mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab) yields a lot of similar problems

Comment: Yeah that is great thanks for both of the reply's :)